# Point of circles : Show that $SC$ is parallel to $AA'$

Tags: geometry, circles

Two circles $M_1, M_2$ with centers $A$ and $B$ respectively intersect outside at a point $C$. .

Let $A'$ be a point on $M_1$ and $B'$ be a point on $M_2$ such that $A'$ and $B'$ are on the same side of the line $AB$ such that $AA'$ and $BB'$ are parallel.

Let $S$ be the intersection point of $AB'$ and $BA'$.

Show that $SC$ is parallel to $AA'$ and calculate the distance from $S$ to $C$ as a function of the two radius.

$$$$

Do we have to show that $\angle A'AS=\angle ASC=\angle AB'B$ to get that $SC$ is parallel to $AA'$ ?

Comment: What does ‘two circles intersect outside’ mean? And moreover at a single point?

Comment: As far I understand that they intersect in such a way that there is just one intersection point. @Bernard

Comment: This is called externally tangent circles, if I understand you well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to recognise the similar triangles, and that $ACB$ is a straight line.

[image]

Notice that since $AA' // BB'$, we have $\triangle AA' S \sim \triangle B'BS$.

This gives $\dfrac {AS}{SB'} = \dfrac {A'S}{SB} = \dfrac {AA'}{BB'} = \dfrac {AC}{CB}$ (radii).

By "ratio of 2 sides, included angle" (also called the SAS similarity criterion), we see that $\triangle BCS \sim \triangle BAA'$. This gives $CS// AA'$ as desired. Now the length of $CS$ follows from similar triangles.

Comment: At the relation $\dfrac {AS}{SB'} = \dfrac {A'S}{SB} = \dfrac {AA'}{BB'} = \dfrac {AC}{CB}$ how do we get the last equality? I mean why is $ \dfrac {AC}{CB}$ also equal to the previous ones?

Comment: As for the second part: we have that $CS// AA'$ so we get that $\triangle AA' S \sim \triangle CAS$, since $\angle A'AS=\angle ASC$, $\angle ASA'=\angle CAS$ and the side $AS$ is common. We have that $\dfrac {AC}{SA'} = \dfrac {A'A}{CS}$. The same holds also with the other circle, i.e.  we have that $CS// BB'$ so we get that $\triangle BB' S \sim \triangle CBS$, since $\angle B'BS=\angle BSC$, $\angle BSB'=\angle CBS$ and the side $BS$ is common. We have that $\dfrac {BC}{SB'} = \dfrac {B'B}{CS}$. Is that correct?

Comment: As they are radii: $AA' = AC, BB' =CB$. You're confusing similarity criteria with congruence criteria; there are almost no "common side" for similar triangles, and the two pairs of triangles you mentioned does not have to be similar. Besides $\angle ASA' \ne \angle CAS$.

Comment: Ahh I see!! So to calculate the length $CS$ do we show that the triangles $\triangle ACS$ and $\triangle BCS$ are similar?

Comment: Those two aren't similar either. As I said, with $\triangle BCS \sim \triangle BAA'$, we would have $\dfrac {BC}{CS} = \dfrac {BA}{AA'}$; most of the unknowns here are actually radii.

Comment: Ahh I got it now!! Thank you very much!! :-)